# Non-standard Turing machines

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory

Turing machines can be encoded as natural numbers. In particular, one can (say, by using the binary representation of a computer program) find a bijection between natural numbers and Turing machines. Now, there exist sets which are nonstandard models of the natural numbers.

Is there work exploring what (according to some reasonable encoding) those Turing machines which are encoded by some non-standard naturals do?

In particular, what, if anything, more can Turing machines in a non-standard model of the integers do that normal Turing machines can't?

Comment: overlap with https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275639/turing-degree-of-a-turing-machine-with-access-to-an-arbitrary-nonstandard-inte

Comment: You might be interested in my blog posts, showing a sense in which every function can be computable in some nonstandard model, using the same universal algorithm: http://jdh.hamkins.org/every-function-can-be-computable/ and more recently  http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-universal-algorithm-a-new-simple-proof-of-woodins-theorem/.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, I saw that one -- but it seems like it's asking about a Turing machine with access to a non-standard integer -- not one that's encoded by one.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, That's an interesting post. I think it answers my question (or is an answer, given that my question is open-ended). Thanks.

Comment: The theorem in my post is closely related to a result of Woodin's (and the follow-up post is explicitly about Woodin's theorem), with more recent advances by Enayat and Blanck; earlier formulations of the result go back to Mostowski and Kripke. I can write up a brief answer here summarizing things if you like.

Comment: I won't trouble you to do that, I read the post (and the succeeding one) which are interesting. However, I have a philosophical question regarding the algorithm p which computes any function f: N -> N on the standard part. p cannot know how to get at the standard part, right?

Comment: So imagining such a function p could exist, how would you access it? If you worked in some model of ZFC (a standard model) then would you be able to define some kind of bijection between a standard model of the naturals and the standard part of p's computation in your non-standard model? Basically would you be able to access the computation f in any sort of computable way?

Comment: The universal algorithm program $p$ is standard finite---I describe it explicitly in the post. What changes is the result of this program if you run it in nonstandard worlds. In the standard world, it never halts on any input. In the various nonstandard worlds, it can halt because it finds, at some nonstandard stage, a certain nonstandard object with the combinatorial properties for which it had been searching. The example shows that it isn't just nonstandard programs that can act weirdly, as in your question, but standard programs can behave in surprising ways in a nonstandard world.

Comment: And about your question (p cannot know how to get at the standard part, right?), the answer is yes, that is right. In a nonstandard model of PA, one cannot define the standard part by any means that can be carried out inside the model, since this would violate the induction axiom of PA. If the nonstandard model could see its own standard part, then it would be able to see that the standardness predicate Std(x) has Std(0) and Std(x)$\to$Std(x+1), but it is not universal, which would violate induction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get it now. So in fact it does compute the function f exactly before it halts -- not on just the standard part of its runtime. I guess the reason it is compatible with diagonalization arguments of non-computability is because any non-computable (for some model) function is computable only in another model. So basically strange results can come just from the fact that you have non-standard runtimes, even disregarding non-standard programs.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: One thing to note is that you can treat this as a standard universal turing machine with access to a non-standard natural number describing a non-standard turing machine.

Comment: Also, which non-standard model are you talking about?

Comment: This is an interesting question to which I don't know the answer. I wonder if the answer will depend on the details of which encoding is used, however.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems like a Turing machine encoded by a nonstandard integer would be able to have an infinite state transition table. (Because, in a vague intuitive sense, a nonstandard integer contains an infinite amount of information, and there is nowhere else for that information to go except for the state transition table and the set of symbols.) So it would be able to calculate uncomputable functions in finite time, just by having an infinite lookup table built in.